# Render images in phantom-pdf

Tags: phantomjs, jsrender, jsreport

I'm using phantom-pdf recipe to render template content. So far so good I could able to generate PDF document successfully but we have new requirement now i.e adding one or more images at the end of the document. Each image should render on its own page. ***Page size should be the Image size*** no header/footer needed.

Images can be of various sizes.

To render the image I'm using HTML tag as part of Template Content

```
<img id="bg" src="@this.Context.Request.Scheme://@this.Context.Request.Host@this.Context.Request.PathBase/Assets/Screenshot.png" /><div style='page-break-before: always;'></div><img id="bg" src="@this.Context.Request.Scheme://@this.Context.Request.Host@this.Context.Request.PathBase/Assets/Untitled.png" />
```

I can see the rendered Image in the PDF document but I see empty white space at the bottom of the page (After rendered image there is white space) [Rendered PDF document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVENb.jpg)

Is there any way using Phantom PDF my Page size will be image size (Header/Footer is not required)??

Currently, the business is using PPT document where each slide is an Image and transform the PPT to PDF.The generated PDF document consists one or more image and each image on its own page. (No white space/No header & footer).

Answer (score 0):

You can scale image size to the full page using css. However you can't adapt your page size based on the image. phantomjs doesn't support each page in the pdf document having a different size. You would need to generate each pdf separately and then use another software to merge them together.

Comment: Thanks Jan for quick response. I will look into other solutions to convert Images to PDF document.